# iPhone : How can I move image on other image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to add small clip art on other image.

I know that I can do this by adding other imageView on the background imageView.

But I want to move(drag) on the clip art on the image.

Is it also possible to scale clip art image like zoom in or out? How?

How can I do this?

Comment: Did u even bother to search for a solution? Stackoverflow and the Internet are full of solutions for that. -1

Comment: i got the solution for scaling but unable to find for dragging !!! :(

Comment: Look at apple's MoveMe sample code - that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html): Apple provides numerous "standard" gestures that are extremely simple to implement.

The gist here is that you would apply the desired gesture recognizers to the clip art image view to provide drag, resize, etc functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the ImageView that you want to drag:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:imageView                                                                                   action:@selector(pan:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];
```

Then, implement the `pan` method with something like this:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.superview];
    CGRect currentFrame = self.frame; 
    currentFrame.origin.x = self.frame.origin.x + translation.x;
    currentFrame.origin.y = self.frame.origin.y + translation.y;
    self.frame = currentFrame;
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.superview];
}
}
```

To scale the ImageView, you can add an UIPinchGestureRecognizer and scale the imageView as you wish.